# React Router DOM: Change match in path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In my app I have a router set up like this

```
  <BrowserRouter basename={props.base_path}>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/views/:view_id/card"
        render={(routerProps) => (
          <>
            <Toolbar {...routerProps} />
          </>
        )}
      ></Route>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Inside `Toolbar` I would like to be able to change the value of :view_id. I know that using `useHistory` I can replace parts of the path but I'm not aware of a way I can specifically target the :view_id part of the path.

What would be the most correct way to change this matched variable with react-router-dom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option I have found is to just pass the path down to the Toolbar and to do something like

```
history.push(props.path.replace(':view_id', opt.value))
```